# Business Objects Enterprise scheduling Multiple Reports into a single email

Tags: crystal-reports, business-intelligence, business-objects

I am Using 2011

I have a number of reports that I have scheduled into an object package.  I would like to be able to bundle all three of the reports up into one email and then send the email so I am not spamming staff with three emails for reports that relate but cant be amalagmated into a single report.

Thanks

Leith
.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a **publication** instead of an object package, you can include all generated files in one email.  You can also optionally have them zipped.